# Algorithm: thinking about an algorithm for "master" and "apprentices" and prove it is optimal

Tags: java, algorithm

The question is You are a master with so many apprentices. You are finishing N tasks with them together, however only you can create the initial creation which takes Ci time for different piece of job. After that you can left this job to one of your apprentices which takes Ai time. One apprentice can only work on one job at a time. What would be an effective algorithm to finish all the jobs with less time? Prove it is optimal.

My solution is get all the time for Ai-Ci, and sort them from big to small, always select the first job in the list and I think that would be save more time. Is that correct? If it is not, could you give me a counterexample? What would be better strategy?

Comment: As a suggestion, this question might exist or be a better question on Mathematics stackexchange.

Comment: Can you add more explanation for your proposed approach?  It is not clear that Ai-Ci is well defined, could there not be more apprentices than jobs in which case you have more Ai than Ci?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Cause I am thinking, you don't wanna your apprentices always waiting there, however you also don't wanna the master spends so much time on his initial creation. Therefore, I think we wanna finish the job which takes more times for apprentices and takes less time for mater. For example, C1 = 1, A1 = 100 will be done before C2 = 50, A2 = 50. Is that clear?

Comment: @KevinO Thanks! I'll look for that.